# ANTLR4 - Is it possible to store a variable of a certain data type within a matched rule?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I would like to somehow store a variable of a pre-determined type (or even an Object) within the matched rule, much like in GNU Bison, where you would define the type that each rule has and therefore the constructors and fields associated with them.

For example (in GNU Bison), if I had predetermined that instances of the **varAssign** rule would be of type `TokenVarAssign`, which has a constructor and two fields (variable identifier and assignment expression), I could do the following:

```
varAssign: id '=' expr {$$ = new TokenVarAssign(); $$.id = $1; $$.expr = $3;}
```

Where **$$** represents the current token being matched (in this case, one of **varAssign**) and **$n** represents the nth token in the rule.

Is it at all possible to achieve the same (or something similar) with ANTLR4.
Up until now, I have been traversing the tree of `ParserRuleContext` objects after parsing the file and constructing my Token objects that way, which has turned out to be much less polymorphic and dynamic.

**Edit in response to answer:** With the following grammar file, I get the error below:

```
grammar Test ;

INT: '0' .. '9' ;
add [int x] returns [int result] : '+=' INT {$result = $x + $INT.int;} ;
```

Error:

```
$ antlr4 Test.g4
error(50): Test.g4:4:4: syntax error: '[int x]' came as a complete surprise to me while matching rule preamble
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define and assign [attributes on parse tree nodes](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules#ParserRules-RuleAttributeDefinitions). You can access the attributes in the visitor and in the grammar file.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the link you attached, but Antler isn't recognising the attribute. I even copied the example rule that was supplied and I still get the following error: **syntax error: '[int x]' came as a complete surprise to me while matching rule preamble**

Comment: Can you append the failing rule in your posting above?

Comment: I am no longer able to edit the comment, but here is the rule: **add [int x] returns [int result] : '+=' INT {$result = $x + $INT.int;} ;**

 I took it straight from the examples in the documentation, and I have a valid rule called INT.

Comment: Are you certain that you use ANTLR4? I tested it with ANTLR4 and it was ok. Yet a complete grammar would allow a more detailed analysis. It can be a small grammar, as long as it reproduces the behaviour which you do not understand. Best attach this grammar to your question (and not as comment) - that would be more readable.

Comment: Edited the original post, thanks for the extra help!

Comment: Your grammar defines a lexer rule before a parser rule. Exchange both lines (`INT` and `add`) and the grammar will compile.

Comment: This link no longer works. Are you able to post what it says? I need "permission" to access it.

Comment: try out this one: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md